# react-native scrollView pinch example

Tags: react-native, scrollview, zooming, pinch

Is pinch to zoom supposed to work just by setting minimumZoomScale and maximumZoomScale? I have a large picture and I want to allow user to scroll both horizontally and vertically and also allow her to use pinch to zoom in and out. The eventual problem will be also to able to detect the tap point. The sample code is as below:

```
  <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <View style={{backgroundColor: 'red', flex: 1}}>
      <Text>Details Screen</Text>
      <Text>Image is {this.state.imageInfo.uri}</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={{flex: 9}} onLayout={this.handleImageViewOnLayout}>
      <ScrollView horizontal={true}
        minimumZoomScale={0.1}
        maximumZoomScale={5}>
        <ScrollView
          minimumZoomScale={0.1}
          maximumZoomScale={5}
          scrollEnabled={true}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={true}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true}
          >
          <TouchableHighlight
            onLayout={this.handleTouchableOnLayout}
            onPress={(evt) => this.handlePress(evt)}>
            <Image
              source={{uri: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/13/Tunnel_View%2C_Yosemite_Valley%2C_Yosemite_NP_-_Diliff.jpg/2560px-Tunnel_View%2C_Yosemite_Valley%2C_Yosemite_NP_-_Diliff.jpg'}}
              style={{
                height: 2560,
                width: 1671
              }}
              />
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </ScrollView>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  </View>
```

Complete code on github: https://github.com/alisalimi25/skroll .
The logic should work both on android and ios.
I really appreciate your help.
Thanks

Comment: Does this code work? If not, what unexpected behavior do you see?

Comment: No, it does not. I can't zoom the image.

Comment: I'm using the code you posted and have no trouble zooming in or out, which is weird. I tested it on iOS device

Comment: Even on ios zoom out and zoom in is not smooth. The image will end up being cut and the proportion is not correct.